# Azure Data Factory v2 Not Null Columns in sink

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, azure-data-factory

I'm trying out Azure Data Factory v2 and I want to pipe data from an SQL source to an Oracle sink.

My problem is, that I have several Not Null columns in my Oracle tables which specify for example the date and time of which a dataset is loaded into Oracle. These columns however aren't existant in the SQL tables so when I want to start the pipeline I get the error that these columns can't be null in the Oracle sink.

My question is now, is it possible to artificially add these columns during the pipeline run so that these columns get filled by the Data Factory?
Can I use a stored procedure or a custom activity for that?
 Or do I have to create a Powershell script which "hardcodes" the values I want to add to the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this in ADFv2 using a query against your source dataset in the Copy activity to insert values.

Using the table ex_employee, with the following configuration in each database:

Source table (SQL):

```
ID int not null,
Name nvarchar(25) not null
```

Sink table (Oracle):

```
ID number(p,0) not null,
Name nvarchar2(25) not null,
CreatedDate timestamp not null
```

In the Source configuration on your Copy activity in ADF, you would select the Query option under Use Query, and input a query, such as:

```
SELECT ID, Name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS CreatedDate FROM ex_employee
```

This will take the existing values from your SQL table, and insert a default value into the result set, which can then be inserted into your Oracle sink.

Answer (score 1):

Does this column has default value ? can you add default to this column then try? I not familiar with oracle pipe data however a similar approach in the below example adding a default value to a not null column.

```
drop table ex_employee
/
create table ex_employee (id number(1) null ,name varchar2(100)  default 'A' not null )
/
insert into ex_employee(id)
select 1 from dual
/
commit
/

selecT * from ex_employee where id=1
```

Comment: Thanks.
No, they don't have a default value. Your suggestion could work for the column that uses the load date, but I have another column which should be filled with the name of the Data Factory Pipeline for which a default value isn't really practical.

It seems I'll have to talk with my boss if it is possible to change that.

Other Ideas are still appreciated though.

Comment: if the sql doesnt have the name of data factory pipeline how then you want to add the data ? why don't you add the data in sql ? @Obongo

Comment: At the moment I am still working with Data factory v1 for which someone who is no longer at the company created a Powershell script to dynamically add the values to the pipeline. Since ADFv2 changed the way the JSONs for the pipeline are generated, we can't use the same script anymore. Since noone here is good with Powershell, I wanted to try a workaround. 
Thanks for your help, it is appreciated. I will try to get it to work with default values, else I will have to learn some Powershell.